# Cosine of one angle in relation to sine of another.

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with a particular final exam question.

> Given that $\alpha+\beta=60°$, and $\cos\alpha=\frac{11}{13}$, find
> the value of $\sin\beta$.

I managed to do the problem by using $\arccos$ and doing it with the calculator.
My question is, is there any other way or formula to solve the problem without using calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin \beta=\sin(60^{\circ}-\alpha)=\sin 60^{\circ} \cos\alpha -\cos 60^{\circ} \sin\alpha = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}\frac{11}{13}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{11}{13}\right)^2}=\frac{7\sqrt3}{26}$$

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

\begin{align}
\sin(A - B) &= \sin(A)\cos(B) - \cos(A)\sin(B) \\
\therefore \sin(60^{\circ} - \alpha) &= \sin(60^{\circ})\cos(\alpha) - \cos(60^{\circ})\sin(\alpha)
\end{align}

Now consider a right triangle with acute angle $\alpha$ and the following sides:

\begin{align}
\text{opposite} &= \; ? \\
\text{adjacent} &= 11 \\
\text{hypotenuse} &= 13 \\
\end{align}